# Javascript I am trying to make a tic-tac-toe game and it doesn't work if the person wins diagonally

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make a tic-tac-toe game and as of right now I am only working on the program knowing when the player with X wins, and it works well, except for when the player wins diagonally. The console doesn't have any errors. Is there something I am missing?
This is the Javascript

```
var player = 0;
var xvalue = 0;
var ovalue = 0;
function tic(a) 
{
    if(player === 0)
    {
        document.getElementById(a).value = 'X';
        document.getElementById(a).disabled = 'true';
        player = 1;
    }
    else if(player === 1)
    {
        document.getElementById(a).value = 'O';
        document.getElementById(a).disabled = 'true';
        player = 0;
    }
    if(document.getElementById('aa').value === 'X') {
        if(document.getElementById('ab').value === 'X') {
            if(document.getElementById('ac').value === 'X') {
                alert("Player 1 has won!");
            }
        }
    }
    else if(document.getElementById('ba').value === 'X') {
        if(document.getElementById('bb').value === 'X') {
            if(document.getElementById('bc').value === 'X') {
                alert("Player 1 has won!");
            }
        }
    }
    else if(document.getElementById('ca').value === 'X') {
        if(document.getElementById('cb').value === 'X') {
            if(document.getElementById('cc').value === 'X') {
                alert("Player 1 has won!");
            }
        }
    }
    else if(document.getElementById('aa').value === 'X') {
        if(document.getElementById('bb').value === 'X') {
            if(document.getElementById('cc').value === 'X') {
                alert("Player 1 has won!");
            }
        }
    }
    else if(document.getElementById('ac').value === 'X') {
        if(document.getElementById('bb').value === 'X') {
            if(document.getElementById('ca').value === 'X') {
                alert("Player 1 has won!");
            }
        }
    }
    else if(document.getElementById('aa').value === 'X') {
        if(document.getElementById('ba').value === 'X') {
            if(document.getElementById('ca').value === 'X') {
                alert("Player 1 has won!");
            }
        }
    }
    else if(document.getElementById('ab').value === 'X') {
        if(document.getElementById('bb').value === 'X') {
            if(document.getElementById('cb').value === 'X') {
                alert("Player 1 has won!");
            }
        }
    }
    else if(document.getElementById('ac').value === 'X') {
        if(document.getElementById('bc').value === 'X') {
            if(document.getElementById('cc').value === 'X') {
                alert("Player 1 has won!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the Html

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
</style>
</head>
<body>
<center>
Tic-Tac-Toe
</center>
<center>
<table border = "1">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input value=" " id="aa" type="button" onClick="tic('aa')">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input value=" " id="ab" type="button" onClick="tic('ab')">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input value=" " id="ac" type="button" onClick="tic('ac')">
        </td>
    <tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input value=" " id="ba" type="button" onClick="tic('ba')">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input value=" " id="bb" type="button" onClick="tic('bb')">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input value=" " id="bc" type="button" onClick="tic('bc')">
        </td>
    <tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input value=" " id="ca" type="button" onClick="tic('ca')">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input value=" " id="cb" type="button" onClick="tic('cb')">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input value=" " id="cc" type="button" onClick="tic('cc')">
        </td>
    <tr>
</table>
<input type="button" value="Restart" onClick="document.location.reload(true)">
</center>
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascripttest.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are already entering `if(document.getElementById('aa').value === 'X') {` in your first check, so wont go to elseif in diagonal. Try `if` instead of `else if`

Maybe you could try to do something like this:

```
//board:
// 0 1 2
// 3 4 5
// 6 7 8
var won = false;
var arr = [
    ["aa", "ab", "ac"],
    ["ba", "bb", "bc"],
    ["ca", "cb", "cc"]
];
var board = [];
for (var row = 0; row < 3; row++) {
    for (var col = 0; col < 3; col++) {
        board[row * 3 + col] = (document.getElementById(arr[row][col]) == 'X');
    }
}

var checks = [
    [0, 1, 2],
    [3, 4, 5],
    [6, 7, 8],
    [0, 3, 6],
    [1, 4, 7],
    [2, 5, 8],
    [0, 4, 8],
    [3, 4, 6]
];
for (var i = 0; i < checks.length; i++) {
    var count = 0;
    for (var j = 0; j < checks[i].length; j++) {
        count += checks[i][j];
    }
    if (count == 3) {
        won = true
    }
}
if (won) {
    //player one won!
}
```

Comment: @user2059810 check code example of a different way to approach the problem

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you are using `else if` incorrectly.

It's difficult to explain, but let's strip down your code to just the `if..else if...`

```
if(document.getElementById('aa').value === 'X') {
}
else if(document.getElementById('ba').value === 'X') {
}
else if(document.getElementById('ca').value === 'X') {
}
else if(document.getElementById('aa').value === 'X') {
```

I'm going to stop there. Why? Because you have the same condition twice! This duplication boils down to "if A... else if A" and in the case of a diagonal win you are expecting that "else if A" to work! Naturally, it won't.

To solve this problem, consider removing the `else` keywords, and when the player wins, use `return` to exit the function immediately.

Comment: I would find a better solution (with minimal code change) to be to replace the nested if statements with `a == X && b == X && c == X` .. then it would even work in the else-if case without a return.

Comment: @user2864740 Yes, that's true. Ideally I'd have an array to store the game's state, an array of tests (indices that make up the lines), and iterate through that :D

Answer (score 0):

I'll bet that if you put an X in 'aa' and then try to win with x's along the bottom row it will also fail.

The problem is with your chaining if statements. Because of the way else-if works, it will only get to the "else" block if the first if statement is false. So if 'aa' is an X, you will never get to any of the other checks except for that first check on the top row.